# Training Error decreasing with each epoch

Tags: neural-network, convolutional-neural-network

I am trying to train a **VGG-19** neural network on **STL-10** dataset containing **5000** images(**500** for each class). And the number of output classes is **10**.

I have made no changes to the architecture except that I reduced the size of fully-connected layer from **4096** to **2048**, keeping the **dropout**(0.5) same

[The reason behind doing this is that, since the number of training images is less, so to avoid over-fitting, I decreased the size of fully-connected layer, but I don't know if this is the right thing to do].

I have also used **Adam optimiser**(learning rate = 0.001) instead of **SGD** as mentioned in the paper.

I have only run the code for only 4 epochs. And I have observed that although the cost is decreasing by very small amount, but the training accuracy is decreasing.

After the *1st* epoch, *cost*:: **2.304091** and *training accuracy*:: **11.99%**

After the *2nd* epoch, *cost*:: **2.303365** and *training accuracy*:: **11.249%**

After the *3rd* epoch, *cost*:: **2.301936** and *training accuracy*:: **10.5625%**

After the *4th* epoch, *cost*:: **2.30415** and *training accuracy*:: **8.1249%**

I want to know, that is this behavior natural or is it due to some fault in the changes I made in the architecture?
Or using less number of layers would have been better? (For example VGG-16)

(This is my first hands-on neural network experience)

Answer (score 1):

I am not very sure about your case, usually I have seen the same problem but in the other direction, you can take a look here:

- [Quora loss drecrease, accuaracy constant](https://www.quora.com/Loss-cross-entropy-is-decreasing-but-accuracy-remains-the-same-while-training-convolutional-neural-networks-How-can-it-happen)
- [Cross validated loss drecrease, accuaracy constant](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/202485/what-could-be-possible-reason-for-accuracy-in-convnets-being-constant-while-trai)

I would guess that your DNN is getting more answers right but without impoving its confidence  a lot.

Regarding your other questions, I would advise you to start with simplest possible model, for example, in this case it would be using the vgg16 (which is widely more used than the vgg19) and the default parameters ( number of neurons, optimization function...) Once you have something working you can start tuning and modifying things.

Comment: I changed nothing, except, I changed the way I was feeding data to `feed_dict`. I was taking the batch as a tensor and again used `eval` on it to get the numpy array. I removd the entire tensor thing and just used numpy arrays directly.

Now, the accuracy started from 2.5%, went up till 7.5% then again decreased to 5%, again increased to 10%, again decreased to 7.5% again increased to 12.5%. Then suddenly dropped to 2.5%. And now rising again

Comment: I am looking forward to do what you advised. Thanks for that.

Comment: I have implemented the VGG16 and as given in the paper. The training accuracy for the first 8 epochs are 12.5%, 12.5%, 12.5%, 10%,5%,2.5%,10%,5%. Can you give me some information on how this training accuracy is actually measured. I am actually passing the last training batch as the batch to measure the training accuracy.